# How do I stop single sign on (SSO) option using Web Authentication Broker

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, yammer

I am developing a Windows Store App which requires user to authenticate using Yammer credentials. I have written the following code to achieve the functionality.

```
var client_id = <<My Client ID >>;
        var client_secret = <<My Client Secret>>;

        string redirectURI = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
        string loginURI = "https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI;

        var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri(loginURI), new Uri(redirectURI));
        if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            var response = result.ResponseData;
            string[] keyValPairs = response.Split('=');
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&code=" + keyValPairs[1];
            HttpResponseMessage JSONresponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string content = await JSONresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         }
```

When I ran the app for the first time it asked me for my credentials and I was able to login.

Now when I run my app , it takes my previous entered credentials and logs in automatically. I am sure that I did not check "Keep Me signed In" option.

I want the app to ask for credentials every time I run it.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to choose the "do not remember password" option the first time you enter a password. You can delete the current saved password by going to the Start screen, type "Credential Manager", open it, under "Web Credentials" look for your password and click "Remove".

Comment: I tried removing all my credentials from Web Credentials , but that did not help .. also tried clearing IE cookies and deleting temporary files but of no success. I did not get any option such as do not remember password which I could check

Comment: Wierd -_- Usually the [remember screen looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P5q5o.png).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an app using the Pocket OAUTH 2.0 API. I am using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx and its `AuthenticateAsync` method but I think the problem is the same.

I had used the `AuthenticateAsync(options, url)` method which ended up -once credentials are saved - I was never able to use a different login so basically could not change accounts.

Tried `AuthenticateAsync(options, url, redirectURI)` method and same problem.

But then I realized that `redirectURI` is set to `GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri` as in your example this seems to trigger SSO.

Changing the `redirectURI` to a custom one (e.g. your own domain) seems to disable SSO and credentials have to be added every time as wanted.

This is easy with the `AuthenticateAsync` method as it uses a `WebAuthenticationBroker`, not sure how to adapt this with the `HttpClient` you use above but I maybe you could use 
`WebAuthenticationBroker`?

But my code example (Javascript but same API):

```
var authweb = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web
var OAUTH_URI = 'https://$WHATEVERSERVICE'
var OAUTH_CODE = '$GOT BEFORE'

var endURI = 'http://$YOURDOMAIN.com' // this is the important part

var authorizeUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(OAUTH_URI
        + '?request_token=' + encodeURIComponent(OAUTH_CODE) // POCKET SPECIFIC PARAM
        + '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(endURI)
        );

authweb.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(
        authweb.WebAuthenticationOptions.none,
        authorizeUri,
        Windows.Foundation.Uri(endURI)
).done(...
```

This way I get a clean (no prefilled or even submitted) login form every time.

Hope this helps?